# Mongoose+NewRelic memory leak (MongoDB cursor leak)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks, mongoose, newrelic

I am trying to fix a memory leak that crashes my production server when monitored with NewRelic.
It seems that there is a know NewRelic issue with MongoDB cursors (cf. link below). And I was wondering if this could be my case since I am using mongoose.js (which handles cursors for me), and if I needed to add some middleware of any kind to handle that myself.

- Anybody ever had this kind of issue with the Mongoose+NewRelic combination?
- Is there a way to make sure that the cursor is closed and released after a find() for example ?

**Know issue:** https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/troubleshooting/large-memory-usage#mongo

(As I understand it, they need to be closed/released manually, not garbage collected, because there are retained by NewRelic for monitoring purposes, causing the leak)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer is in that link. "Solution: Ensure every cursor created in your application is closed by calling cursor.close() after the application finishes processing the results of the query." you could post some code of using the cursor.

Comment: Mongoose is using cursors internally, I don't. My question is precisely: is cursor.close() already done by Mongoose or not? And if not, how can I access the cursors in order to do it myself?

Comment: Mongo should implicitly close cursors for you. You shouldn't need to do it yourself.